# How to get share link with dropbox api in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, dropbox-api

I want to make an app that lets a user upload a file to dropbox and then get options to share that file. How can I get a dropbox link for a file? It seems like I could use
client.sharing.createSharedLink(path:"/myfile")
but how would I access that data as a String?

Comment: That is the right method for getting a shared link. What issue are you having? It returns a `PathLinkMetadata`: https://dropbox.github.io/SwiftyDropbox/api-docs/latest/Classes/Sharing/PathLinkMetadata.html . That has a String `path` property, which contains the share link.

Comment: @Greg So if I try to get a url like this: 'let newLink = client.sharing.createSharedLink(path: "/myFile")' how can I access the path property to get the actual string?

Comment: Apologies, I meant to say `url`, not `path`, above. I'm adding an answer with sample code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a sample of how you could use `createSharedLink` in SwiftyDropbox to get a shared link to a file, in this example at the path /test.txt.

```
Dropbox.authorizedClient!.sharing.createSharedLink(path: "/test.txt").response({ response, error in
    if let link = response {
        print(link.url)
    } else {
        print(error!)
    }
})
```

Comment: Do you know how can I get a direct link for download from a regular dropbox link. (redirected link)?

Answer (score 0):

Building on @Greg's answer, you can simply replace `www.dropbox.com` with `dl.dropboxusercontent.com` and `dl=0` with `dl=1` to get the direct share link.