# Creating a shared link to file using SwiftyDropbox

Tags: ios, swift, dropbox

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34212268/how-to-get-share-link-with-dropbox-api-in-swift#_=_)

While trying to use Dropbox SwiftyDropbox for creating a shared link for my file I always get the error:

```
Bad Input: Error in call to API function "sharing/create_shared_link": request body: could not decode input as JSON
```

I have created an App Folder and I can successfully write files to my Dropbox. All attempts on calling the methods in `Dropbox.authorizedClient!.sharing` generate this error. Does anyone have any idea to why?

Comment: I have tried both SwiftyDropbox version 2.0.2 and 2.0.3 since I saw that there might be a bug in the newer version, this does not help however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue in SwiftyDropbox 2.0.3, and I can reproduce the error output you get using 2.0.3. The same code works properly for me in 2.0.2 though. I would double check that you downgraded to 2.0.2 successfully. For example, either of these specs will give you 2.0.3:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'SwiftyDropbox'
```

or

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'SwiftyDropbox', '~> 2.0.2'
```

Instead, you can explicitly specify 2.0.2 as such for now:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'SwiftyDropbox', '2.0.2'
```

Then, run `pod update` to get that version. The output from `pod update` will indicate what version was used.

Comment: My problem was just as you thought `pod 'SwiftyDropbox', '~> 2.0.2'`
My SwiftyDropbox wasn't downgraded to 2.0.2, it works fine using your help